# Django call delete function with a button

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to add a delete function to my project. so I can remove objects from the database without using the admin page.

I'm getting this error when I try to render 'exercise_detail.html'

Reverse for 'exercise_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exercise/(?P[^/]+)/delete/$']

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    evolution = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
    enddate = models.DateTimeField()
    logo = models.BinaryField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Exercise: {self.name}\t Evolution: {self.evolution}"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import loader
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Exercise, Units
from .forms import ExerciseForm

def exercise_delete(request, name, *args, **kwargs):
    ex_del = Exercise.objects.get(Exercise, name=name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        ex_name.delete()
        return redirect('../')

    context = {
        'ex_del': ex_del,
    }

    return render(request, 'landing.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.landing),
    path('newexercise/', views.new_exercise),
    path('newunit/', views.new_unit),
    # ex: unit/7th Comm/
    path('unit/<str:short_name>/', views.unit_detail),

    # ex: exercise/Cobra Gold/
    path('exercise/<str:name>/', views.exercise_detail),
    # edit exercise
    path('exercise/<str:name>/edit/', views.exercise_edit),
    # ex: delete exercise
    path('exercise/<str:name>/delete/',
         views.exercise_delete, name='exercise_delete'),
    ]
```

exercise_details.html

```html
        {% extends 'base.html' %}
    
    
    
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">  
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light"> 
        <h3>{{ ex_name.name }}</h3>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" 
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/exercise/{{ ex_name.name }}/edit/">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" >Edit</button>
            </a>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
              <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </a>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Exercise?</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this exercise
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'exercise_delete' ex_name.name %}">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
      <div class="row p-3">
        <h5>
          Evolution: {{ex_name.evolution}}
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row p-1">
        <p5>
          Start Date: {{ex_name.startdate}}
        </p5>
      </div><div class="row p-1">
        <p5>
          End Date: {{ex_name.enddate}}
        </p5>
      </div>
    
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block content-another %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 border">
        Class I
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 border">
        Class III
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 border">
        Class V
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think I'm  passing the incorrect arguments in my html file.

I also replaced the argument exercise.name with name=name, what I have in my views and I get this error.

Reverse for 'exercise_delete' with keyword arguments '{'name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exercise/(?P[^/]+)/delete/$']

Edit:

ex_name is defined here in views.py

```
def exercise_detail(request, name, *args, **kwargs):
ex_name = get_object_or_404(name=name)
context = {
    'ex_name': ex_name
}
return render(request, 'exercise/exercise_detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a mistyping here:

```py
def exercise_delete(request, name, *args, **kwargs):
    ex_del = get_object_or_404(Exercise, name=name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        ex_del.delete()
        return redirect('../')

    context = {
        'ex_del': ex_del,
    }

    return render(request, 'landing.html', context)
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'exercise_delete' name=ex_name.name %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete exercise">
</form>
```

Comment: and I suggest that you use `pk` instead of `name`

Comment: I replaced Exercise.objects.get with get_object_or_404 and I get this error Reverse for 'exercise_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['exercise/(?P<name>[^/]+)/delete/$'] I probably should have mentioned that I have tried get_object_or_404 previously.

Comment: here, in file.html, you call your instance Exercise? <a href="{% url 'exercise_delete' Exercise.name %}"> what is your instance name?

Comment: it shoudl be: `ex_name.name` and not `Exercise.name`

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to ex_name and it deleted all exercises, but at least I'm making progress. NVM, it just takes me to exercise/<str:name/delete which is a blank page

Comment: make sure ex_name is just one exercise and not all the queryset of Exercise class

Answer (score 0):

@ladhari has answered my question, replacing my button containing the function with this

```
<form action="{% url 'exercise_delete' name=ex_name.name %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Delete exercise">
</form>
```

and changing Exercise.name to ex_name.name

Comment: Thank you!glad to know that it resolved it